# Какого рода турецкий "ил"?

Tags: терминология, род

Узнал, что есть термин ***ил*** — провинция в Турции (раньше употреблялся *"вилайет").* Вот что написано в [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80_(%D0%B8%D0%BB)) про один из илов в Википедии:

> **Бурдур** (тур. *Burdur)* — ил Турции, расположенн**ая** в юго-западной части страны.

Из неё видим, что автор этих слов считал *"ил"* словом **женского рода**, видимо, имея в виду мысленно, что это провинция. Однако само слово звучит как слово **мужского рода**, тем более что есть ещё *"ил",* который на дне водоёмов.

*Так как же правильно?*

Comment: В других статьях Википедии пишется смягким знаком (иль) и употребляется в мужском роде: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 а также https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Из неё видим, что автор этих слов считал "ил" словом женского рода

Нет, это не так. Чтобы понять причину возникновения такого рода ошибок, нужно знать механизмы работы Википедии. Дело в том, что разные участники зачастую вносят правки в отдельные предложения Википедии, совершенно не беспокоясь о том, чтобы эти правки каким-то образом соответствовали информации в других статьях, разделах или даже внутри самих предложений. В данном случае один из участников в более ранней версии писал:

> Бурдур (тур. Burdur) — провинция (ил) Турции, расположенная...

Затем другой участник удалил слово провинция. "Патрулирующий" согласился с удалением слова и тоже не дочитал предложение до конца.

Оставим за скобками, что в других статьях Википедии "ил" пишут с мягким знаком – "иль" (следуя "Большой российской энциклопедии", а не словарям), но к данному вопросу это не имеет отношения.

> Так как же правильно?

Это существительное мужского рода.

Comment: Спасибо большое, гризли, за ответ и за то, что изучили историю правок! Самому даже в голову не пришло. :)